# Refreshing/Reload From form 1 to form 2

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
}
```

I have that code on my Form1. So that will automatically run `Form2_Load`. Is it possible that when I click a button on Form1. `Form2_Load` will run again without having to close Form2.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  `Form2_Load` will only run when `Form2` *loads*.  So you'd need to open a new instance of `Form2`, which you can do with the exact code you've shown.

Comment: If the code is worth running at all, put it in a function with a good name  which you call whenever you need to. Coding events with any amount of logic is bad.

Comment: @David Thanks man. Sorry. I'm still a C# newbie. I was trying to use the Observer pattern. From Form1 to Form2. Form 2 being the Observer. When a button on Form1 is clicked it will send a message update to form2. And a textbox in Form2 will have the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment:

> When a button on Form1 is clicked it will send a message update to form2. And a textbox in Form2 will have the message.

(First of all, this isn't the Observer Pattern.  But that's ok, it doesn't need to be.)

First, `Form1` needs to retain its reference to the instance of `Form2`:

```
public class Form1
{
    private Form2 Form2Instance { get; set; }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2Instance = new Form2();
        Form2Instance.Show();
    }

    // the rest of your code
}
```

Now other code on `Form1` can reference that instance.  This is because you don't want to actually *reload* all of `Form2` any time anything changes.  You just want to "send a message update to form2".

Now, how will `Form2` *receive* that message?  It can expose a method.  Something like this:

```
public class Form2
{
    public void Update(string newValue)
    {
        someTextBox.Text = newValue;
    }

    // the rest of the code
}
```

Now code on `Form1` can call that method on the instance of `Form2` that it references.  So when you click a button on `Form1`, you might do this:

```
Form2Instance.Update("some value");
```

This would "send a message" to the instance of `Form2`.